# Magento 2 admin fieldset form input float issue

Tags: magento2, adminform, custom-field, fieldsets, input

I have created admin form with fieldsets. The issue is it isn't accepting float values and rounding them to integer values.

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'free_over',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'free_over',
                'label' => __('Free Over'),
                'title' => __('Free Over'),
               'required' => true,
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! It was database datatype issue. Set it to float(10,2).[image]